# BaseX: Public REST API without authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, basex

Is it possible to create a public REST API in BaseX, so that clients do not need to authenticate at all?

This public API should be read-only. What I already have done is creating a user called `HTTPGuest`, which has read access to certain databases.

Then I have tried `basexhttp -UHTTPGuest`. But the API still wants to have credentials via Basic Authentication.

Comment: If you use BaseX 8.6 and later, it should actually be sufficient to specify the user on command line, just as you did.

Comment: Yes, I realised that myself, after the answer has been posted. The issue in my case was actually another one: The API requested Basic Authentication, when I executed `basexhttp` from a working directory that was not the parent directory of the `basexhttp`. I have now a wrapper script, which basically does just `cd /.../basex/bin; ./basexhttp`. But the answer by Jens Erat is nonetheless useful for me, because now I don't have to always use the `-U` option anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide default credentials by modifying the `web.xml` file, which is usually located at `~/BaseXWeb/WEB-INF/web.xml`. This file contains following block>

```
  <!-- REST Service (can be deactivated by removing this entry) -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.basex.http.rest.RESTServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- service-specific credentials
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.basex.user</param-name>
      <param-value/>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.basex.password</param-name>
      <param-value/>
    </init-param>
    -->
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here, uncomment the `<init-param/>` subtree and add the user/passphrase combination to the `<param-value/>` elements, for example

```
  <!-- REST Service (can be deactivated by removing this entry) -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.basex.http.rest.RESTServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.basex.user</param-name>
      <param-value>HTTPGuest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.basex.password</param-name>
      <param-value>super-secret-passphrase</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: A minor addition: With BaseX 8.6, the password need not be specified anymore (as it is known to the server instance anyway).

Comment: Works perfectly, even without setting `org.basex.password`. Thank you both!